MS graph api listing items in a drive in sharepoint required mandatory filter query
I have a sharepoint site. I want to retrieve list of all items(files) in a drive.
For that I used this api:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items
For which I get following response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "The 'filter' query option must be provided"
  }
}

I don't want to filter anything, need all the items.
Expectation:
List of all items (files and folders) in a drive
Actual:
Mandatory 'filter' query required.
What I tried doing?

Went through doc, nothing found
Tried both beta as well v1.0 api versions
Tried with graph java sdk, same error


I have one document library with below files in SharePoint site named sridemosite:

When I ran this API call to list all files in above drive, I too got same error:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives/driveId/items

Response:

Alternatively, make use of below API call by appending /root/children to list all the files in drive:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives/driveId/root/children

Response:

Reference:
List the contents of a folder - Microsoft Graph
UPDATE:
If items present in root drive is a folder, you can make use of separate API call like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/drives/driveId/root:/foldername:/children

To get files in all sub folders, you can recursively list the contents of each folder.

It will list items only in root folder, not in subfolders

Thank you for pointing that out! If you have any additional information or API calls to include, please feel free to edit my answer. I'm open to all suggestions to improve it

It's a good start point. First get items in the root folder - you've already described how to do it. If an item is a folder then call /v1.0/sites/siteId/drives/driveId/items/driveItemId/children to get items in the folder. Recursively for all subfolders.

I’ve updated my answer to include your suggestion about handling items in subfolders. Your input is much appreciated!

Well it defeats the purpose of mentioned api. Recursively iterating through subfolders is very expensive for me. Can microsoft team not fix this api or provide an explanation why does it expects a mandatory filter ?
Or just provide an alternative api for the same.

Would you tell me whether your issue has been resolved or have any update? If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.
